# My app dosent work on sony xperia z1 bu works on some other devices

Tags: android, emulation, forceclose, sony-xperia

i have an text based app and it works fine in most devices and in emulator but on sony xperia z1 it causes force close,
1.is it possible to emulate xperia z1 on android virtual device manager?how?
2.do you have ideas about reasons of this problem?

Comment: Post the stacktrace of the force close.

Comment: Stacktrace please...

Answer (score 0):

You should test your app on this phone and explore logcat for error details. If you have no access to the device you could do one of the following:

1. Install sony add-on and try to test on their avd: http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sony-add-on-sdk/install-the-sony-add-on-sdk/
2. If app is published on market there is section in admin area where you could see crash information if user have sent crash details after it happened.
3. There is a service where you could test your apps on almost any real device and see logcat - http://www.perfectomobile.com/ - it's pretty expensive, but I think they have free trial with limited number of devices - may be xperia is among these devices.